# Quick way to "multiply" every element in a list with another list in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have two lists ['a', 'b'] and ['m', 'c']. Is there a quick and dirty way to "multiply" them in such a way that the resulting array would be the list of combinations of each element in both arrays, i.e.,

```
[ ['a', 'm'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'm'], ['b', 'c'] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a comprehension to iterate the two lists and pair:

```
list1 = ['a','b']
list2 = ['m','c']    

list3 = [[a, b] for a in list1 for b in list2]

Out: [['a', 'm'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'm'], ['b', 'c']]
```